# Proving the uniform convergence of $f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I need to show that $f_n(x) = \frac{\ln(1+nx)}{n+x}$ converges uniformly on $X = [0,10]$. 
I have tried proving by Cauchy criterion, as well as from the definition (where limit function is $f =0$), but no results so far.

Comment: Show that you can find a positive sequence $a_n$ such that $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le a_n$ for all $x \in [0,10]$ and $a_n \to 0$. Do you see why this would imply uniform convergence to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $R>0$. Then for $x\in [0,R]$ and for $n\geq 1$, 
$$0\leq \frac{\ln(1+nx)}{n+x}\leq \frac{\ln(1+nR)}{n}.$$
What may we conclude as $n$ goes to infinity?

P.S. Actually, the convergence is uniform in $[0,+\infty)$. Since $\ln(1+nx)$ is concave, its graph stays under the tangent line at $x=n$:
$$\ln(1+nx)\le \ln(1+n^2)+\frac{n(x-n)}{1+n^2}.$$
Therefore, for $x\geq 0$,
$$0\leq \frac{\ln(1+nx)}{n+x}\leq \frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n+x}+\frac{n}{1+n^2}\cdot \frac{x-n}{n+x}\leq \frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n}+\frac{n}{1+n^2}.$$

Comment: In fact, the convergence is uniform for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @MarkViola You are right. One can show that for $x\geq 0$,  $0\leq \frac{\ln(1+nx)}{n+x}\leq \frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n}$.

Comment: Robert, I was able to show that the maximum value of $\frac{\log(1+nx)}{n+x}$ occurred at a value of $x_n>\sqrt{n}$ and that this maximum was $\frac{n}{1+nx}\le \frac{n}{1+n^{3/2}}$, which suffices to show UC on the positive reals.

Comment: I used the inequality given by the tangent line to the concave function $\ln(1+nx) $at $ x=n $.

Comment: The tangent line to $\log(1+nx)$, at $x=n$, is $y=\log(1+n^2)+\frac{n(x-n)}{1+n^2}$.  So, $\log(1+nx)\le \log(1+n^2)+\frac{n(x-n)}{1+n^2}$.  Then, clearly $\frac{\log(1+nx)}{n+x}\le \frac{\log(1+nx)}{n}\le \frac{\log(1+n^2)}{n}+\frac{x-n}{1+n^2}$.  Then ???

Comment: @MarkViola Note that the function $h(x)=\frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n+x}+\frac{n}{1+n^2}\cdot \frac{x-n}{n+x}$ is decreasing for $n\geq 3$. Anyway I obtained a weaker inequality which shows the uniform convergence. See my P.S..